# React-GA events are firing off in debug console but not showing up in GA

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, react-ga

I have been trying to make this work for a few days, and nothing is working. The events are simply not being captured no matter what I do.

I import ReactGA at the top

```
import ReactGA from "react-ga";
```

I initialize it after import

```
ReactGA.initialize("TRACKING-ID", {
  debug: true
});
```

I create a function to handle the tracker

```
const GASignInHandler = name => {
  ReactGA.event({
    category: "Dashboard Home",
    action: `User Signing In As ${name}`,
    label: "Tracking users every time they sign in.",
    nonInteraction: true
  });
};
```

Inside my functional component called DashHome, and inside the return I call this.
Pretty much if signedIn = true, run this function, if not run the console.log. This is for testing purposes obviously but I still don't see this event being logged in GA. It fires off in debug.

```
{signedIn ? GASignInHandler(userEmail) : console.log("signin not true")}
```

> [react-ga] with fieldObject:
>   {"hitType":"event","eventCategory":"Dashboard
>   Home","eventAction":"User Signing in as My","eventLabel":"Tracking
>   Users Every Time They Sign In.","nonInteraction":true} log.js:2
>   [react-ga] with trackers: undefined

I also have all the tags that GA told me to put into my public/index.html.

Answer (score 2):

Putting this into index.js fixed the problem.

```
(function initAnalytics() {
  initGA("Tracking ID");
})();
```

The initGA function is manually created and is as such (this file is called index.js)

```
import ReactGA from "react-ga";

export const initGA = trackingID => {
  ReactGA.initialize(trackingID);
};

export const PageView = () => {
  ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname + window.location.search);
};

export const Event = (category, action, label) => {
  ReactGA.event({
    category,
    action,
    label
  });
};
```

I have also removed all the scripts that I had in public/index.html. I only have react-ga init.

It also seems you must put

> ReactGA events

into a useEffect hook if youre using functional components.

Comment: >It also seems you must put ReactGA events into a useEffect hook if youre using functional components.
This is not strictly true. It's often a good idea, so they don't fire again every time the component re-renders; but in some cases (such as, when re-rendering signifies an important action), you may wish them to do so.